# Use two VisualStates at once in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, visualstatemanager

I have a Windows Store app.  In this app, the layout needs to adjust when the app gets snapped and the width is smaller than a certain value `x`.  Then, when the page is resized past a smaller `y`, the appbars need to adjust their layout.  I am using `VisualState` control to do this, and checking whether I need to adjust the layout when the size of the page is changed, like this:

```
this.SizeChanged += (s, args) =>
{
    pageSizeChanged();
};
```

This is how I am doing my `VisualState`s, in case that matters:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryView"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
            <Storyboard>

                SnappedCondition(s)...

            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="AppBars">
            <Storyboard>

                AppBarsCondition(s)...

            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Now, my problem is, I don't want to duplicate all my code from `Snapped` into `AppBars`, like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="AppBars">
    <Storyboard>

        SnappedCondition(s)...
        AppBarsCondition(s)...

    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

I would rather use `PrimaryView` and `Snapped` to set the main layout and have `AppBars` work independently of them so I could set it in a way similar to this:

```
void pageSizeChanged()
{
    String state = (MainPage.ActualWidth > 750) ? "PrimaryView" : "Snapped";
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, state, false);

    if (MainPage.ActualWidth < 450)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "AppBars", false);
    }
}
```

Now it obviously won't work the way I am doing it now, but I am wondering if there is a way to make it work so I don't have to duplicate a bunch of code that needs to be changed together every time I change it?  Of course, I could do it in code-behind, but I'd rather have it in my XAML file.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but your approach just saves typing a few lines, but can't improve the readability of code, think it is kind of over-refactoring. The normal way would be switch-case into 3 ranges: 0-450, 450-750, and >750, and go to 3 visual states respectively.

Comment: @kennyzx Yes, I may have to do that.  However, I don't want to because then I will have a duplicate code that will need to be maintained in synchrony.

Comment: Perhaps setup the Appbar in code behind and don't change it when there is a visual state change? I have a simple app where instead of visual states I just move/resize a few components in code behind. Works great. This way you can force the appbar to the same state regardless with no duplicate code.

Comment: @pumpkinszwan Well, it needs to change.  There are several buttons, and it gets too long for the window, so they need to drop down into two rows.  Yes, I will probably have to do it in code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the states do.

States in the same VisualStateGroup are mutually exclusive, but the app can set different states in different VisualStateGroups.

If the AppBar and Snapped states don't change the same properties on the same items then you can put them in separate VisualStateGroups and have them both apply simultaneously. If the states conflict with each other then you'll need to keep them separate.

If you set up something like the following you can then set both a ViewStates and an AppBarStates group simultaneously:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryView"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
            <Storyboard>

                SnappedCondition(s)...

            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AppBarStates">
       <VisualState x:Name="NoAppBars" />
       <VisualState x:Name="AppBars">
            <Storyboard>

                AppBarsCondition(s)...

            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```